# VueJs Ensure two selects have different options

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have removed a lot of unrelated code, so let me quickly explain the process I am currently trying to deal with.  Someone uploads a CSV file, this file could be huge.  To avoid sending something so big to the server, I want to process it on the client, as I know which columns I need to keep.

So when the CSV is uploaded, I quickly parse the first row to get the column names.    I then assign this to `fileHeaders`

Once this happens, the following displays

```
<div v-if="fileHeaders !== ''">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectId">Select ID Column</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectId" v-model="selectedIdCol">
            <option v-for="fileHeader in fileHeaders" :value="fileHeader">{{fileHeader}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectDate">Select Date Column</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectDate" v-model="selectedDateCol">
            <option v-for="fileHeader in fileHeaders" :value="fileHeader">{{fileHeader}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

So it is 2 select options, each displaying all `fileHeaders`.  All I need is for the user to let me know what header represents the ID column, and what header represents the Date column.

Within the script, I am currently binding the selected inputs to data

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                fileHeaders: '',
                selectedIdCol: '',
                selectedDateCol: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Now I wanted to either do one of two things, whatever makes more sense.  Firstly, if one option is selected, then I need to make sure this option does not appear in the second select.  However, I may need to hide the second select in this case until the first option is selected?

Or, I produce some real time validation, whereby the are unable to select the same option twice?

What would make more sense, and how would I go about doing this?  I have seen things like using mounted, but not sure if this a good option?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using computed properties to populate both select elements:

```
<option v-for="fileHeader in idHeaders" :value="fileHeader">
    {{fileHeader}}
</option>
```

...

```
<option v-for="fileHeader in dateHeaders" :value="fileHeader">
    {{fileHeader}}
</option>
```

...

```
computed: {
    idHeaders() {
        return this.fileHeaders.filter(hdr => hdr !== this.selectedDateCol);
    },
    dateHeaders() {
        return this.fileHeaders.filter(hdr => hdr !== this.selectedIdCol);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check selected columns before sending data to server and show proper warrning to user

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { 
    selectedIdCol: null,
    selectedDateCol: null,
    fileHeaders: ['id', 'column1', 'columnData', 'column3', 'column...']
    
  },
  methods: {
  
    send: function(event) {
    
      if(this.selectedIdCol == this.selectedDateCol) alert('Choose two different columns!')
    },
    
   
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-if="fileHeaders !== ''">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectId">Select ID Column</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectId" v-model="selectedIdCol">
            <option v-for="fileHeader in fileHeaders" :value="fileHeader">{{fileHeader}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selectDate">Select Date Column</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectDate" v-model="selectedDateCol">
            <option v-for="fileHeader in fileHeaders" :value="fileHeader">{{fileHeader}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button @click="send">SEND</button>
</div>
</div>
```